# Examples of code that compiles but executes differently in C versus C++

Tags: c++, c

I am looking for more examples that compile under both C (any standard) and C++, but run differently. As an example, I found this in comp.lang.c, which produces 8 for C, and 512 for C++:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct A { char block[8]; };

int main(void) {
    struct B {
        struct A {
            char block[512];
        } a;
    };

    printf("sizeof(struct A) = %lu\n",
        (unsigned long) sizeof(struct A));
    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone have any more examples of this, especially ones not using this particular trick?